# Why is the diamond norm called like that?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology, soft-question

The [diamond norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_norm) is a measure of the distance between two quantum channels. If $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ are two channels, then the diamond norm is defined as

$$ \delta^{\diamond}(\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2)=\max_{\rho_{AR}}\delta((\mathcal{E}_1\otimes\mathcal{I}) \rho_{AR},(\mathcal{E}_2\otimes\mathcal{I}) \rho_{AR})$$

where the optimization is over bipartite states $\rho_{AR}$, $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity channel and $\delta$ is the trace distance.

Is there any particular reason why this is called the "diamond" norm, perhaps a geometrical interpretation?

Comment: I’m not familiar with anything about quantum channels, but I suspect this diamond norm is equivalent to an $L^1$ norm—that norms has diamond isocontours for a given reference state.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures It's a supremum over a trace norm distance of extensions of the map - not really equivalent to an L1 norm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the "diamond norm" is called like that since it is denoted as
$$
\|\cdot\|_\diamond
$$
(and not vice versa).  After all, one has to use a symbol - why not a diamond?

In any case, what you write is the diamond norm distance (i.e. the distance induced by the diamond norm).